# Develop a PHP script that sends you a daily email an associative array

Tags: php, json

How can I develop a php file that send me an email an asociative array with all the information of the last ads formatted in a JSON file?

I have this Json code:

```
{
    "26":{
        "adUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/index.php?page=search&sCategory=26",
        "title":"Engineering Geologist Figueres",
        "salary":"2300.00 Euro \u20ac",
        "category":"ENGINEERING - ARCHITECTURE",
        "publishedDate":"2013-05-07",
        "modifiedDate":"2013-05-27",
        "country":"Spain",
        "region":"Girona",
        "city":"Figueres",
        "cityArea":"Vilatenim",
        "address":"Pla Del Marqu\u00e8s, 13",
        "description":"<p><b>THIS ADVERT IS NOT RELA[... cropped to sample ...] ts and acting as represenattive on site.<\/p>",
        "imageUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/oc-content\/uploads\/65.jpg"
    },
    "30":{
        "adUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/index.php?page=search&sCategory=30",
        "title":"Engineering Barcelona",
        "salary":"2300.00 Euro \u20ac",
        "category":"ENGINEERING - ARCHITECTURE",
        "publishedDate":"2013-05-07",
        "modifiedDate":"2013-05-27",
        "country":"Spain",
        "region":"Barcelona",
        "city":"Barcelona",
        "cityArea":"",
        "address":"",
        "description":"<p><b>THIS ADVERT IS NOT RELA[... cropped to sample ...] ts and acting as represenattive on site.<\/p>",
        "imageUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/oc-content\/uploads\/48.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: I can help you with this if you can better explain what exactly it is you need. Currently, I have no idea.

Comment: Imagine you're looking for a new job, but you haven't time to check out this site every day.
Develop a PHP script that sends you a daily email an asociative array with all the information of the last ads formatted in a JSON file.

Thats What I have to do, and the Json file is the one that I posted before :/

Comment: So you already have the JSON array and you simply want to send this to your mail? Is that all?

Comment: I think phpMailer and cronjob would do the job. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Comment: Yes I got the Json that I posted there and I want to send it to my email every day with the information of the last ads formatted
Says me that too:  *ad id -> Advert identificator integer (index.php?page=item&id=26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This php script should email you every time you run (of cuz you have to change php mailer setting). All you need to do is set up a CronJob on your hosting server and set it to run this script file once a day. Hope this help..

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "26":{
        "adUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/index.php?page=search&sCategory=26",
        "title":"Engineering Geologist Figueres",
        "salary":"2300.00 Euro \u20ac",
        "category":"ENGINEERING - ARCHITECTURE",
        "publishedDate":"2013-05-07",
        "modifiedDate":"2013-05-27",
        "country":"Spain",
        "region":"Girona",
        "city":"Figueres",
        "cityArea":"Vilatenim",
        "address":"Pla Del Marqu\u00e8s, 13",
        "description":"<p><b>THIS ADVERT IS NOT RELA[... cropped to sample ...] ts and acting as represenattive on site.<\/p>",
        "imageUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/oc-content\/uploads\/65.jpg"
    },
    "30":{
        "adUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/index.php?page=search&sCategory=30",
        "title":"Engineering Barcelona",
        "salary":"2300.00 Euro \u20ac",
        "category":"ENGINEERING - ARCHITECTURE",
        "publishedDate":"2013-05-07",
        "modifiedDate":"2013-05-27",
        "country":"Spain",
        "region":"Barcelona",
        "city":"Barcelona",
        "cityArea":"",
        "address":"",
        "description":"<p><b>THIS ADVERT IS NOT RELA[... cropped to sample ...] ts and acting as represenattive on site.<\/p>",
        "imageUrl":"http:\/\/www.parseme.vacau.com\/oc-content\/uploads\/48.jpg"
    }
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$last_arr = end($arr);

foreach ($last_arr as $key => $value) {
    $message .= $value . '<br>';
}

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

?>
```